apa7 get rid of running head on title page
I run MacTex and use apa7.
The class option man brings a format that is almost compliant with the requirements of my institute.
Only I would like to replace the running head on the title page by the logo of the institute. I see the following steps
a) remove running head from the title page and b) add some graphic on the right spot on the title page. The \thispagestyle{empty} also removes the page number; that is NOT what I want, I have to keep it.
here is how the code looks like
\documentclass[man,donotrepeattitle, 12pt, a4paper]{apa7}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
 \usepackage{csquotes}
 \usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
 %\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
 
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{color,soul}
 \usepackage{enumitem}
 \usepackage{makecell}
 \usepackage[american]{varioref}
 

% the title commands 
\title{{\small{(working title)}}\\
Conceptual Change Towards Mathematics\\
{\large{- the difference between two methods of teaching -}}
}

\shorttitle{Develop Computational Thinking}

%\shorttitle{Computational Thinking}
\authorsnames{Flavia Surpol}
\authorsaffiliations{Master Educational Sciences Open University{,} The Netherlands}

\duedate{Aug-2025}

\authornote{
Student number: 1234675\\
E-mail address: student@university.com\\
Course code and name: X34 Mathematics\\
Supervisor: prof. Power\\
Number of words: 5600\\
Date: 01-02-2023
}


\abstract{Notes about two mathematics ways of teaching} 
    

% section numbering
\setcounter {secnumdepth}{4}

\definecolor{EMPTY}{RGB}{255,255,255}



%\addbibresource{../../b-bib/thesisPlan.bib}

%\includeonly{t-test}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction} 
Some text

%\include{section1}
%\include{section2}

%\printbibliography
\end{document}


The fancyhdr package is the usual way to manage headers and footers.

Unrelated: Do remember that macros like \large does not take arguments.

Change the default title  page style. apa7 uses the package fancyhdr.

\documentclass[man,donotrepeattitle, 12pt, a4paper]{apa7}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
%\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

%\usepackage{graphicx} % already loaded
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[american]{varioref}


% the title commands 
\title{{\small (working title)}\\ %<<<<<<<<<<
    Conceptual Change Towards Mathematics\\
    {\large -- the difference between two methods of teaching --} %<<<<<<<<< changed
}

\shorttitle{Develop Computational Thinking}

%\shorttitle{Computational Thinking}
\authorsnames{Flavia Surpol}
\authorsaffiliations{Master Educational Sciences Open University{,} The Netherlands}

\duedate{Aug-2025}

\authornote{
    Student number: 1234675\\
    E-mail address: student@university.com\\
    Course code and name: X34 Mathematics\\
    Supervisor: prof. Power\\
    Number of words: 5600\\
    Date: 01-02-2023
}


\abstract{Notes about two mathematics ways of teaching} 


% section numbering
\setcounter {secnumdepth}{4}

\definecolor{EMPTY}{RGB}{255,255,255}



%\addbibresource{../../b-bib/thesisPlan.bib}

%\includeonly{t-test}

\fancypagestyle{titlepage}{% <<<<<<<<<<<< added
    \lhead{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}% your logo here <<<
    \rhead{\thepage}%
}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \section{Introduction} 
    Some text
    
    %\include{section1}
    %\include{section2}
    
    %\printbibliography
\end{document}

Notice the changes made to \title.
\title{{\small (working title)}\\ %<<<<<<<<<<
    Conceptual Change Towards Mathematics\\
    {\large -- the difference between two methods of teaching --} %<<<<<<<<< changed
}


Result is as desired. Good solution

@BenJ If the solution solves your problem, you should accept it and/or upvote it

The title change does not give the desired effect; the main text "Conceptual Change..." is not the original size; small is maintained for what ever reason
